# Converting Textbox to Integer, Taking String from Array

Tags: c#, integer

I'm trying to convert the user input from a textbox to an integer (in c#), and then output a value from an array with the index of that integer. Here's a small part of my code:

```cs
 public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();
        string[] Cmaj = new string [7];
            Cmaj[1] = "C";
            Cmaj[2] = "D";
            Cmaj[3] = "E";
            Cmaj[4] = "F";
            Cmaj[5] = "G";
            Cmaj[6] = "A";
            Cmaj[7] = "B";


       int roman = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
       textBox4.Text = Cmaj[roman];

}
```

But each time I run this, I get an error about "int roman = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);" (Listed below). I originally had Convert.ToInt32 instead of int.Parse, but I saw another question about this topic that said to use parse rather than convert. This, however, didn't change much. What should I do?

Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Thanks.

Comment: *I get an error about "int roman = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);"*  doesnt it seem like we might need to know the error message?  If you are trying to convert user input, you ought to use `TryParse()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added the error. When I use TryParse, I get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: In the constructor, textBox3.Text is probably still empty. Also, note that arrays are 0-based, so you should initialize Cmaj from [0] to [6].

Comment: Shouldn't it be filled by the user input? The private textbox class for that textbox is empty.

Comment: Yes, but you are still in the constructor, so no user inut has happened until that moment of time. You need to move the code to an event handler that is triggered e.g. when the user types in something, leaves the field or presses a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the constructor of your component. So the text is probably empty and cause an exception.

Probably you want to add the parsing logic on an event like text changed or button clicked.

So from the form builder add the event handler, than move the logic into that method.

To better understand when each metdod il called I suggest you to add a break point on the first `{` of each method, and you can follow the event flow.

Is a good idea to manage error: you can wrap with a try...catch or use int.TryParse that requires an out variable.

Comment: I put my code into the TextChanged event handler (private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)), but now roman in my main body "doesn't exist in the current context."

Comment: what do you mean with main body?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more precise. The class: public partial class Form1 : Form

Comment: there is not a main body, this is a construcotr for the form. in that part just leave initialize component and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use deferent way

1. `Convert.ToInt32(string);`
2. `int val = 0;
   Int32.TryParse(string, out val );`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying, but I tried both of these and I got the same error.

Comment: System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Still didn't work. It was mentioned in the comments that I should move the code to an event handler.

Comment: I don’t know about what error for your code but try debug your code , what is handle textbox or what is output or try static test